# Make two floating divs stay next to each other

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/ovvnnhgt/1

I designed a site which is responsive, it looks kind of weird in jsfiddle (on my screen at least it doesn't show the maximum resolution layout) but you can see the idea.

Zoom out the page all the way and you'll see the div "content" under the div "sidebar." Then zoom in and you'll see the content's width shrink.

My problem is I want the content div to the right of the sidebar div while it does this (where it looks like the sidebar is squishing the content) but I can't get it to work no matter how hard I mess around with the code.

The maximum resolution layout has it so when you change the width the content div moves closer to the sidebar div and then I wanted the next resolution layout to follow that idea but have the content div squish a bit before finally turning into a mobile friendly layout but it goes under while changing width.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1070px) {

.contentwrap {
width: auto;
float: left;
}

}
```

Once it hits this width I have the entirety of content float to the side, the sidebar is on so that when I change the width it will push it towards the sidebar but instead it does this almost perfectly it just moves down.

Comment: You can do this easily with flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. If you have time I recommend watching this turoial for a good understanding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7EIAgfkhmg

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it. Do I have to drastically change my code? I had spent a lot of time with this layout and looking to find the least problematic way to change my current code to achieve this. Edit: This seems promising. I'll have to study it after.

Comment: Most answers to this question will direct you to Flexbox. It is the future (at least for now) of CSS. It is in your best interest to adapt sooner rather than later and it's super easy to use. Once you learn it, it makes things 10x easier. You won't have to change too much, but yes there will be changes although it is more than worth it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it was that big. I'll study up!

Comment: While I understand your not wanting to undo all of your hard work up to this point, using a responsive framework such as flexbox or bootstrap will make the project fly by in the end. For this current problem, you are not experiencing "squishing" because you have a width set to your container in pixels. Setting `.contentwrap` and `.sidebarwrap` as %s should help. Also, your sidebar is floating outside the wrap.

Comment: Bookmarked that flexbox tutorial. Thanks for linking that! flexbox is the future

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:
Rename your second section div contentwrap the same as the first section sidebarwrap (http://screencast.com/t/i2GSBaiox62). Then give your sidebarwrap css width of 45% (http://screencast.com/t/dpQg9orW5v5r).
Is this what you need?

Comment: Not quite. With that there is a huge white gap between the two divs and it doesn't quite work how I want it to. Thank you though! I'll probably just go with the Flexbox method.

Answer (score 0):

May b this will be helpful:
There are 3 ways of doing that.

1) You can use Percentage for that.

2) You can use Media-Query to set every pixel.

3) You can use Bootstrap or Foundation framework. (I suggest you this)